# How to prevent Navigation Menu from breaking up when Company Image is present

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Been playing with the size of my Navigation Menu for a while now, just started to make an example of it using jsFiddle. Did it without any images, and the darn thing worked flawlessly. So I added an example logo the menu splits when the screen width is being decreased.

How Can I Prevent this? **Note each fiddle has the menu screen collapsed. Enlarge the width of the window to view the issue**

[Fiddle With Logo Image](https://jsfiddle.net/qwbev3o1/2/)

[Fiddle without Logo Image](https://jsfiddle.net/qwbev3o1/6/)

Code with Logo Image

```
<div class="nav navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <!---->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!--                    <div class="thumbnail_container">
                                          <div class="thumbnail">-->
      <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="#">
        <img id='logo-white' class='img-responsive resize logo-white' src='https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png' alt='Company Logo' />
      </a>

      <!--                        </div>
                                      </div>-->

      <!--</div>-->
    </div>
    <div class='navbar-header'>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="myNavbar">
      <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">-->

      <div class="menu-header-container">
        <ul id="menu-header" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li id="menu-item-113" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-95 current_page_item menu-item-113"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Teacher</span></a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-112"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Administrator</span></a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-111"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Parent</span></a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-114" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-114"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Blog</span></a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-115" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-115"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Sign In</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--<div class="free-trial-header">-->
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large free-trial-header" href="#"> Free Trial</a>
      <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large free-trial-header ft">Free Trial</button>-->

      <!--onclick="location.href='http://google.com';"-->
      <!--</div>-->
      <!--</ul>-->
      <div class="navbar-right center-block">
        <!--                      nav navbar-nav -->


        <div class="menu-country-container">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-nav dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" id="region-btn">Canada
              <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li data-value="en-ca"><img width="24" height="12" src="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/canada-24x12.png" class="menu-image " alt="Canada" srcset="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/canada-24x12.png 24w, http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/canada-36x18.png 36w, http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/canada.png 48w"
                sizes="(max-width: 24px) 100vw, 24px" /></li>
              <li data-value="en-us"><img width="24" height="13" src="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/usa-24x13.png" class="menu-image " alt="USA" srcset="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/usa-24x13.png 24w, http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/usa-36x19.png 36w, http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/usa.png 48w"
                sizes="(max-width: 24px) 100vw, 24px" /></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <input hidden="true" id="language" value="en-CA">
        </label>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When this split happens the two items on the right are placed on the second line when there is ample of space still between them.

Comment: Ran without issues here. The only visual problem that I see is with 2 buttons at right.

Comment: Ugh I meant right not left. Are you able to pinpoint the issue? I have resized the logo, removed any padding and still not much luck, I got it so that I have only the right most item popping down now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no room for everyone.. If you really want 2 buttons right make part of the menu, you should put them into `<ul>` as list item.

And mainly make logo shrink size as width gets smaller, and don't let it overflow - bootstrap won't do it for you:

```
 .navbar-brand {
   height: auto;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
 } 
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
   .navbar-brand .logo-white {
     height: 40px
   }
 }
```

Comment: Tell me about it, I am going to try adding the two extra items into <ul> for this is a headache.

Comment: Nice but the logo and the remainder of the items are shifting. This is similar to what I was experiencing before I paused...

Comment: You'd never believe it, but by setting the CSS property of letter-spacing: 1 px, fixed the issue. Even in the JSFiddle the lettering is closer than what I initially had and now everything is resizing without breaking. :)

Comment: If I get the time later I'll post the solution.